# Can't reach ElasticSearch installed on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes

This is the [official](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch) command to create elasticsearch on docker:

```
$ docker run -d --name elasticsearch --net somenetwork -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:6.6.1
```

Now, I want to install ElasticSearch on single-node (one container), on Kubernetes. I wrote the following deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  ports:
  containers:
  - name: elasticsearch
    image: elasticsearch:6.6.1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 9200
    - containerPort: 9300
    env:
    - name: discovery.type
      value: "single-node"
```

And when I deployed it, I got "pod/elasticsearch created", without errors.
When I access the logs of the pod, I don't see errors.
Now I try to access it on browser, but I don't see it.
I tried localhost:9200, cluster-info:9200, publish_address:9200 (as seen in the logs)... but I can't see it. How can I access elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have kubernetes service to expose the elasticsearch pod. I would suggest to go through this link 
[link](https://medium.com/google-cloud/a-guide-to-deploy-elasticsearch-cluster-on-google-kubernetes-engine-52f67743ee98)